# Annotation on top of views text?

Tags: 7

Is there a contrib module out there that provides the text equivalent of [image marker](http://drupal.org/project/imagemarker)? E.g. I have views output and i want to place a post it on top of it.

The closest thing i've seen is the annotation field for Drupal 5 which is a bit outdated and i don't really know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Image Annotator](http://drupal.org/project/image_annotator) module.

> The module allows you to annotate images, and works in combination with [field_collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection). The module defines a new field called 'Image Annotator' that can be linked to an image field, so you can add multiple markers to an image.

Comment: Will it annotate on top of views text? It doesn't sound like it from the project description provided above.